# postgresql return true if table relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have a query for a table, garage. Garages have cars linked to them through column (garage_id).

I want a postgresql query that will return all the garages, but also will return true in a seperate column if it has at least one car assigned to it.

For example:

```
Garage A name, no cars
Garage B name, 2 cars
Garage C name, 1 car
Garage D name, no cars
```

Should return:

```
Garage A name, false
Garage B name, true
Garage C name, true
Garage D name, false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select g.name, bool_or(c.garage_id is not null)
from
    garage g
    left join
    car c on g.garage_id = c.garage_id
group by g.name
```